# Is there a way to pass piped data through ggmap like you can with ggplot to the geoms?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, ggmap

While exploring with ggplot a common workflow is to do some data manipulation and then pipe directly into a ggplot(). When you do that, all of that manipulation flows nicely through the ggplot into the geoms with no variables needed. Like so:

```
data %>%
  filter(route %in% c('01','08','15')) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf() + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label=route))
```

If however you want to use a ggmap() for a nice background, then there doesn't appear to be a way to use the piped workflow. You have to save the manipulations to a variable first, which isn't a huge deal, but would love to know if there's a way to avoid it.

This doesn't work:

```
background = get_stamenmap(....) # somewhat irrelevant to the question

data %>%
  filter(route %in% c('01','08','15')) %>%
  ggmap(background) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label=route))
```

Thought maybe trying to force the data into ggmap() might help but it doesn't

```
background = get_stamenmap(....) # somewhat irrelevant to the question

data %>%
  filter(route %in% c('01','08','15')) %>%
  ggmap(background, data=.) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  geom_sf_text(aes(label=route))
```

Or maybe there's some other way to combine ggplot() and ggmap() to accomplish it? I know I can save off the manipulated data as a variable and then hard-code that into each geom_sf() layer, but it's just not as convenient and thought I might be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `magrittr::%>%` infix operator expects to pass the data as the first argument of the first expression in a `+`-chain as you have here. Unfortunately, you want to pass it to one of the not-first expressions. You can use a `{`-block.

```r
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr) # for %>%, could do magrittr as well

### from ?get_stamenmap
bbox <- c(left = -97.1268, bottom = 31.536245, right = -97.099334, top = 31.559652)
background <- get_stamenmap(bbox, zoom = 14)

### from my brain
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(x=runif(4, bbox[1], bbox[3]), y=runif(4, bbox[2], bbox[4]), lbl = sample(LETTERS, 4))
dat
#           x        y lbl
# 1 -97.10167 31.55127   Q
# 2 -97.10106 31.54840   O
# 3 -97.11894 31.55349   X
# 4 -97.10399 31.53940   G

dat %>% {
  ggmap(background) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), data = .) +
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = lbl), data = ., color = "red",
            hjust = 0, vjust = 0)
}
```

[image: sample ggmap with additional data piped in]

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, that definitely helps! I'm guessing specifically that ggplot() does some magic to pass data to subsequent geoms that isn't otherwise possible with ggmap(). This is a good alternative.

Comment: Yes, `ggplot` keeps a semblance of "data used for the plot", where all `geom_*` added to the plot work on that data unless given `data=` explicitly. Since `ggmap` is using a specific object (and not necessary a frame of "other things" you want layered on top of it, the semblance of data passing to follow-on `geom`s is not the same (if even present, I haven't looked deeply). With all `ggplot`-layers, one can always use explicit data, which is why we can work around the issue. Glad it helps!

Comment: You can also use the bizarro pipe: `dat ->.; ggmap(background) + geom_point(aes(x, y), data = .) + geom_text(aes(x, y, label = lbl), data = ., color = "red", hjust = 0, vjust = 0)`. Or simply put the word `data` where you want the data and not try and stuff it through a pipe (which makes things harder to debug)